# how to add some features of an incremental game I am working on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Hey Guys so hoping to get some help on this, I have searched and searched all night and cannot find a simply way explaining how to implement these three features:

This is one of the effects i want - http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

When you click the cookie it pops up +1 and then fades away, If you apply upgrades it changes the number it displays and increments.

What's the best way to implement this? I have searched and searched and only come up with one or two jquery plugins which display popups when used, But there is not enough documentation or something explaining how to achieve the effect i want. also how to make it appear where my mouse is? I would even be happy if it just displayed in the middle of the image that i click.

Also is there a better way to store my number? At the moment my counter is a variable called "snowballs" and the display is a span which updates every second. is there a better way to store this number and display it? prefarably i would love to use a custom counter like this flipclockjs is this possible?

I have put all my code into a jsfiddle page but the image i click is a local file so it does not display. but at least so you can see my code i have provided the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/edznycyy/1/

Thanks so much for any help.

Code below

```js
// Upgrades

var snowballs = 0;

var penguins = 0;
var penguinsps = 0.1;

var igloos = 0;
var igloosps = 0.5;

var eskimos = 0;
var eskimosps = 1.0;

var polarBears = 0;
var polarBearsps = 2.0;



// snowball functions to increase value

function snowClick(number){
    snowballs = snowballs + number;
    document.getElementById("snowballs").innerHTML = prettify(snowballs); 
}


function userClick(number){
 snowballs = snowballs + number;
 document.getElementById("snowballs").innerHTML = prettify(snowballs);
}




//Buy functions

function buyPenguin(){
    var penguinCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.15,penguins));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(snowballs >= penguinCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        penguins = penguins + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        snowballs = snowballs - penguinCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('penguins').innerHTML = penguins;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.15,penguins));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('penguinCost').innerHTML = nextCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};

function buyPolarBear(){
 var polarBearCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.15,polarBears));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(snowballs >= polarBearCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        polarBears = polarBears + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
     snowballs = snowballs - polarBearCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('polarBears').innerHTML = polarBears;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    };
    var nextPolarBearCost = Math.floor(200 * Math.pow(1.15,polarBears));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('polarBearCost').innerHTML = nextPolarBearCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};

function buyIgloos(){
    var iglooCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.15,igloos));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(snowballs >= iglooCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        igloos = igloos + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        snowballs = snowballs - iglooCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('penguins').innerHTML = penguins;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
        document.getElementById('igloos').innerHTML = igloos;
    };
    var nextIglooCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.15,igloos));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('iglooCost').innerHTML = nextIglooCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};

function buyEskimo(){
    var eskimoCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.15,eskimos));     //works out the cost of this cursor
    if(snowballs >= eskimoCost){                                   //checks that the player can afford the cursor
        eskimos = eskimos + 1;                                   //increases number of cursors
        snowballs = snowballs - eskimoCost;                          //removes the cookies spent
        document.getElementById('eskimos').innerHTML = eskimos;  //updates the number of cursors for the user
        document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;  //updates the number of cookies for the user
    };
    var nextEskimoCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.15,eskimos));       //works out the cost of the next cursor
    document.getElementById('eskimoCost').innerHTML = nextEskimoCost;  //updates the cursor cost for the user
};












//makes a number neater
function prettify(input){
    var output = Math.round(input * 1000000)/1000000;
 return output;
}




//Save Load and Delete Functions

function save(){
    var save = {
        snowballs: snowballs,
        penguins: penguins,
        igloos: igloos,
        eskimos:eskimos,
        polarBears:polarBears
    }
    localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};

function load(){
    var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    if (typeof savegame.snowballs !== "undefined") snowballs = savegame.snowballs;
    if (typeof savegame.penguins !== "undefined") penguins = savegame.penguins;
    if (typeof savegame.igloos !== "undefined") igloos = savegame.igloos;
    if (typeof savegame.polarBears !== "undefined") polarBears = savegame.polarBears;
    if (typeof savegame.eskimos !== "undefined") eskimos = savegame.eskimos;
    document.getElementById('penguins').innerHTML = penguins;
    document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;
    document.getElementById('igloos').innerHTML = igloos;
    document.getElementById('polarBears').innerHTML = polarBears;
    document.getElementById('eskimos').innerHTML = eskimos;

};

function deleteSave(){
 localStorage.removeItem("save")
    snowballs = 0;
    penguins = 0;
    igloos = 0;
    eskimos = 0;
    polarBears = 0;
    document.getElementById('penguins').innerHTML = penguins;
    document.getElementById('snowballs').innerHTML = snowballs;
    document.getElementById('igloos').innerHTML = igloos;
    document.getElementById('polarBears').innerHTML = polarBears;
    document.getElementById('eskimos').innerHTML = eskimos;
}






function updateSPS(){
    var sps = (penguins * penguinsps) + (polarBears * polarBearsps) + (eskimos * eskimosps) + (igloos * igloosps);
    document.getElementById('SPS').innerHTML = prettify(sps);

}





function devGive(){
 snowballs = snowballs + 100
 document.getElementById("snowballs").innerHTML = prettify(snowballs);
}




window.setInterval(function(){
 
 snowClick(penguins * penguinsps);
    snowClick(polarBears * polarBearsps);
    snowClick(eskimos * eskimosps);
    snowClick(igloos * igloosps);
 save();
  
}, 1000);

window.setInterval(function(){
    updateSPS();
    
   

        
}, 100);
```

```css
body {margin: 0px; }
body > div {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow:row wrap;
}


body > div > header,nav,main,prices, left,right,bottom, footer {
 background: #7FE3F0; border-radius: 7px; margin: 5px; padding: 20px;
}

body > div > header { order: 1; height: 100px; flex: 0 1 100%;font: bold 30px Tahoma;text-align: center; }

body > div > nav { order: 2; height: 50px; flex: 0 1 100%; font: bold 30px Tahoma; text-align: center;}

body > div > prices { display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; order:6; width: 200px; flex: 0 1 300px; }


 

#price {
 width: 200px;
 margin: 10px;
 font: bold 15px Tahoma;
 padding: 5px;


}

body > div > main { 
 order: 4;
 text-align: center;
 min-height:400px; 
 flex: 1; 

}






body > div > right { display: flex; flex-flow:column wrap; order:5; width: 300px; flex: 0 1 300px; }

body > div > right > box1 > h1 { font: bold 20px Tahoma;}
body > div > right > box1,box2,box3,box4 { display: flex; max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px; border-radius: 7px; margin: 1px; padding: 5px; }
body > div > right > box1,box2,box3,box4 > span { display: flex; margin: 5px;}
body > div > right > box1,box2,box3,box4 > img { display: flex; max-width: 70px; max-height: 70px;}





body > div > left { order:3; width: 200px; flex: 0 1 600px; }



#snowball {
 width: 350px;
 height: 350px;
}


body > div > bottom { 
 order: 7; 
 height: 100px; 
 flex: 0 1 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 10px Tahoma; 
}
body > div > bottom > img {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
}

body > div > footer {
 order: 8;
 height: 100px;
 flex: 0 1 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font: bold 20px Tahmo; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
<title> Winter Fun!</title>
</head>
<body>
 



 <div>


  <header>Winter Fun!</header>

  <nav>
   Snowballs: <span id="snowballs">0</span>
   <br />
   Snowballs Per Second: <span id="SPS" >0</span>

  </nav>

  <left>

  </left>

  <prices>

   
   <box1 id = "price">Penguin Cost:<span id="penguinCost">10</span></box1>
   
   
   
   <box2 id = "price">Igloo Cost:<span id="iglooCost">50</span></box2>
   
   
   
   <box3 id = "price">Eskimo Cost:<span id="eskimoCost">100</span></box3>
   
   
   
   <box4 id = "price">Polar Bear Cost:<span id ="polarBearCost">200</span></box4>



  </prices>

  <main >
   <img title = "Click Me!" id="snowball" src="snowball.png" onclick="userClick(1)">
   
  </main>

  <right>
   <box1>

    <img id="penguins1" src="penguin.png" onclick="buyPenguin()">
    <span id="penguins">0</span>
    
   </box1>

   <box2>
    <img id="igloos1" src="igloo.png" onclick="buyIgloos()" >
    <span id="igloos">0</span>
   </box2>

   <box3>
    <img id="eskimos1" src="eskimo.png" onclick="buyEskimo()" >
    <span id="eskimos">0</span>
   </box3>

   <box4>
    <img id="polarBears1" src="polarBear2.png" onclick="buyPolarBear()" >
    <span id="polarBears">0</span>
   </box4>

   
    
   
   
   

  </right>
  
  <bottom>
   <h1> Options!</h1>
   <img id = "save1" src="save.png" onclick="save()">
   <img id = "load1" src="load.png" onclick="load()">
   <img id = "delete1" src="delete.png" onclick="deleteSave()">



  </bottom>
  





  <footer>
   
   copyright MPWebDesign 2014
  </footer>


 








</body>

 <body onload = "load()">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="snow.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the "popup" with jquery, position it under the mouse with css, and animate the element with jquery pretty easily. See the below commented code.

As for storing the data, `localStorage` is probably the quickest/easiest way.

Here is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edznycyy/5/)

**Note that `localStorage` is just that, local.** As in stored on the physical machine you are using. So if you were to visit this page on your laptop and do some stuff, then visit the page from your desktop, you would not see the changes you made using the laptop.

If users need to access the values from different devices, you'll need a backend (server side) solution like using php to connect to a mySql database to store and retrieve the information probly with a little ajax to keep everything asynchronous.

If you have this need and dont want to learn `php` , `mySql`, and `ajax` i'd recommend [Parse](http://parse.com) which is basically a super easy to use backend storage API that you can interact with using just javascript. I use parse in several projects and would be lost without it.

---

***EDIT: As for the placement of the code in the actual page***

[This page](http://affordable-glass.com/test/popuptest.html) loads jQuery itself in the head tag, then loads the html, then loads the jQuery functions I wrote for you. **This works** because when the functions are called, jQuery has already been loaded and the elements we want to affect already exist on the page.

[This page](http://affordable-glass.com/test/popuptest2.html) loads jQuery itself in the head tag, then loads the jQuery functions I wrote for you, then loads the html elements we want to affect. **This does not work** because when the functions are called, the elements we want to affect dont yet exist on the page.

[This page](http://affordable-glass.com/test/popuptest3.html) loads jQuery itself in the head tag, then **lists** the jQuery functions I wrote for you, then loads the html elements we want to affect. **This works** because the functions are wraped in `$(function(){ PUT CODE HERE });` which tells the page "hey page, I know Im putting this code up here at the top but, I want you to run the code inside it only after the page has fully loaded".

---

```
    $( "#myClickDiv").click( function(event) {
        // get current time in milliseconds since 1970/01/01 to use as a unique id for the popups
        var id= new Date().getTime(); 

        // use Ternary opperator to ask "does a value exist for `ownedPenguins` in local storage"
        // if yes get that value, if no set val to 0

        var val= localStorage.getItem("ownedPenguins") ?  localStorage.getItem("ownedPenguins") : 0;

       // create a div and add it to the main div 
       $( "#main").append('<div class="countDiv" id="'+id+'">'+val+'</div>');

        // get the added div and set its position to that of the cursor
       $("#"+id).css( {position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX});

         // annimate the added div
              $("#"+id).animate({ "top": "-=100px","opacity": "0" }, "slow",function(){
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
              );
            // in the above
            // "top": "-=100px" tells it to animate the div 100px up
            // "opacity": "0" tells it to animate the div's opacity to 0
            // "slow" is a shorthand speed setting
            // function() {$(this).remove();} is a callback that will remove the element upon ompletion of the animation
    });


// use `localStorage` to track how many of each thing a user has
$( "#myBtn").click( function(event) {
    // use Ternary opperator to ask "does a value exist for `ownedPenguins` in local storage"
    // if yes get that value, if no set val to 0
    //get, increment, and set the value of `ownedPenguins` in `localStorage`
    var val= localStorage.getItem("ownedPenguins") ?  localStorage.getItem("ownedPenguins") : 0;
        val++;    
    localStorage.setItem("ownedPenguins", val);
})
```

;

Comment: Thanks so much for this helpful information, now you have given my some code to pull apart and figure it out!

Comment: For some reason when i copy this code it doesn't work for me? I have even started a new file and just put the basic html, css and javascript in then it still doesn't work? Is there a specific version of jquery i need to use? I put jquery 2.1.3 in the main directory and pointed the html file to it using "<script src="jquery.js"></script>"

Comment: Where do you have the jQuery code above in your html file? Is it in the `<head>` tag or down at the bottom just before the `</body>` tag and does it come after the `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`?

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe that's whats been causing me so much grief all day.. :P

Comment: glad it helped, you could put the jQuery code in the head tag if you want but you'd need to put it inside this function `$(function(){ PUT CODE HERE });` this will tell the page to run the code inside it only once the page has fully loaded. The problem you had was because otherwise, the code is parsed by the browser from top to bottom if you have the jQuery above the html elements it tries to bind the event handlers to the elements before they exist on the page

Comment: wait, now im confused... I had the "<script src="jquery.js"></script>" in the bottom of my document just before the /body and thats the only file i need right? the rest goes into the javascript file? when i put the html, css and javascript in, I can see the box and the button but when i click no popup... hope thats clearer.

Comment: @MIke I added 3 example pages to my answer to explain what im talking about with the placement of the code. go to them and use `view source` to see the structure and the comments, the first and third page both work while the second does not and they explain why

Comment: Thanks for your help, i appreciate you taking the time..I have tried again and once i rename all the files to appropriate functions it doesnt work... here is a gif of what happens - http://gyazo.com/1e02f1f261f487e904213e9489aced6c

also here is a jsfiddle with my code - http://jsfiddle.net/7p3e07z8/1/

Comment: Where you have `<img title = "Click Me!" id="snowball" src="snowball.png" onclick="userClick(1)">` , take out the `onclick="userClick(1)"`. It shouldn't be there but there may be more, i'm still looking

Comment: I just started a whole new page from scratch and now it works so i think that you're right, i don't have that onclick and now it works.

Comment: Also, in your code #snoball is an img in mine it was a div to compensate, give `<main>` an id like `<main id="main">` then change  `$('#snoball').append('<div class="countDiv" id="'+id+'">'+val+'</div>');` to  `$('#main').append('<div class="countDiv" id="'+id+'">'+val+'</div>');` that'll get it working in your old code :)